# Load Average Graph Values in pnp4nagios less than 1.0 denoted by a value "m"

Tags: rrdtool, nagios

In the graphs generated by pnp4nagios that track server load averages, if the load is less than 1.0, the value is represented by a number in the hundreds denoted by the letter "m".

What does the "m" stand for?

[image: example pnp4nagios graph]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The m stands for [milli](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milli-), a prefix meaning 1/1000.